# import logging function from a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to import a function which initializes two different logging handlers with different levels. The problem is that for option 1 below, I'm getting the root logger, and for option 2, I can't get any logs to print to screen.

Does anybody have any thoughts or suggestions that might help?

Option 1
TestModule:

```
def set_logger(
    app_name=argv[0][:-3]):
    logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='[%(levelname)s][%(module)s][%(asctime)s] - %(message)s',
    filename="test.log"
    )
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s][%(module)s][%(asctime)s] - %(message)s')
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
```

Option 2 TestModule:

```
def set_logger(
    app_name=argv[0][:-3]):

    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s][%(module)s][%(asctime)s] - %(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger(app_name)
    stream_log = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    stream_log.setFormatter(formatter)
    file_log = logging.FileHandler("test.log")
    file_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_log.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(stream_log)
    logger.addHandler(file_log)
```

in Script:

```
from Module import set_logger
import logging

if __name__ == "__main__"
    set_logger()
    logging.info("start_app")
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You call `getLogger('')`, so you get the root, right?

Comment: That's correct - but when I pass sys.argv[0] instead, it just doesn't print anything. or even if I were to pass __name__ it stops generating logs to streaming

Answer (score 0):

In option 2, you are initializing a logger via logging.getLogger()
You need to return the logger in that function and call it using the returned logger,

```
if __name__ == "__main__"
    logger = set_logger()
    logger.info("start_app")
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain when I tried this it didn't really make a difference - let me get back to you on that @micebrain. It's possible I missed something

Comment: Doesn't log to file